# How to execute code from another program as a result of a command

Tags: python, c++, shell

I'm thinking on how to design a program that as a result of all events, checks a **command file** (which essentially holds key-value pairs where the key is a command and the value is the code to execute) and runs that command's matching code.
It'll be run on a unix/linux machine.

For simplicity's sake, the program will be as follows:
It'll wait for the user's input. When the user inputs a valid command (i.e a command that appears in the commands file), the matching code will be executed. If it doesn't match any command it'll print "No matching command".

So if my command file looks like:

```
run1='a.py'
run2='b.py'
```

and I enter "run1" then a.py will be executed. If I enter "run3" then "No matching command" will be printed.

I want to implement this in C++ and I've seen similar implementations where people used `system()` to execute the commands but this feel like a bad way to achieve this.

What other options do I have to achieve this?

p.s - I wrote in my example that the code being run is in python. I'm not sure I want that to be the only option (so I'll need to be able to identify the type. Lets assume I can do that). 
Is this still achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are LOTS of options. `system("a.py");` will do what you want (assuming python is installed correctly on the system you are running on). If that is the "best" solution really depends on what you want to achieve, and that isn't entirely clear from your question.

Most other solutions will be more or less system specific. You could, for example, in Unix/Linux use `fork()` and one of the flavours of `exec()` [with python as the actual executable, and `"a.py"` as the file to run in python], but that won't work in Windows, where you would have to use, for example, `spawn()` (again with python as the executable file and for example `"a.py"` as the code to run).

Comment: I've updated my question. I intend this to be run on a linux machine.
The essence of what I want to achieve is in the example I wrote and in the description I gave it. 
If you want to know specific information please ask. I'm not entirely sure what else to add.

Comment: Ok, so you can certainly use `system` for that. Any particular reason you think that won't do what you need?

Comment: It absolutely will. It just seems like a twisted way to achieve this. If however there is no other option that's what I'll do.

Comment: All other options are quite a bit more complicated. I (and most others) tend to follow the principle of "Use the simplest solution that is sufficient for what you want to achieve". Of course, it will do fork, exec a shell and then start python from the shell, etc. But realistically, you will probably not notice the difference between this and doing your own fork/exec function (unless you are doing many thousands of these things, and a.py and b.py are really quite trivial - in which case it may be better to implement them in some other way)